# Adding bool values

Tags: c, casting, boolean, addition, relational-operators

```
bool comapare(int val)
{
  if(val>5)
   {
     return true;
   }
 return false;
}

int myFunct(int x,int y)
{
  int count = 0;
  count = (int)compare(x) + (int)compare(y);
  return count;
}
```

I want to add bool values as above. Is typecasting it as such the best approach to do so. Any comments.

Comment: well why would you want to add bools, what are you hoping will happen?

Comment: Have you tried *not* casting?

Comment: In C, there's nothing special about the `bool` type. It's just another integer type. Behind the scenes, it may actually *be* an `int`, or it could be a smaller type like `short` or `char`. Like other integer types that are smaller than an `int`, it is promoted to `int` when used in an expression. So you don't need a cast to use a `bool` with the addition operator.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to cast the values. You could just write

```
 count = compare(x) + compare(y);
```

The operands will be promoted to the type `int` due to the integer promotions and the result also will have the type `int`.

And as the count can not have a negative value it is better to declare it as having an unsigned integer type as for example `size_t` or at least `unsigned int`.

Also the function compare can be written simpler

```
bool comapare(int val)
{
    return val > 5;
}
```

In C the type `bool` is a typedef name for the integer type `_Bool`.

Answer (score 1):

I see why you are doing it but its confusing to read. BTW the cast is not needed

```
int myFunct(int x,int y)
{
  int count = 0;
  count = compare(x) + compare(y);
  return count;
}
```

works fine, but I would do

```
int myFunct(int x,int y)
{
   int count = 0;
   if (compare(x)) count++;
   if (compare(y)) count++;

    return count;
 }
```

The intent is much clearer.